# How to prevent remote access in iptables

Tags: iptables, firewall

I have iptables set up with docker-compose but my whitelisting of only the ip addresses I want doesn't seem to be working as the server is still getting remote access attempts:

```
Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 95: "host all all all md5"
2021-09-01 21:36:42.132 UTC [8821] FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
2021-09-01 21:36:42.132 UTC [8821] DETAIL:  Role "postgres" does not exist.
```

How can I fix my iptables to be setup correctly? What have I done wrong here?

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i eth1 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xx.xx/xx -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT (where x is removed ip addresses)
-A INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xx.xx/xx -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i br-1de8a78b46b8 ! -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -m iprange --src-range 82.208.14.110-82.208.14.119 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.2/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 6379 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.3/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 2368 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.4/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.5/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5900 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.5/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.8/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.9/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.9/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.6/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9300 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.18.0.6/32 ! -i br-1de8a78b46b8 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9200 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i br-1de8a78b46b8 ! -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o br-1de8a78b46b8 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

**EDIT:**

Here is my docker-compose config:

```
  postgres:
    image: "postgres:12.1"
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    ports:
      - '5432:5432' # removed 127.0.0.1: - adding firewalls in iptables

    restart: "${DOCKER_RESTART_POLICY:-unless-stopped}"
    stop_grace_period: "${DOCKER_STOP_GRACE_PERIOD:-3s}"
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - /opt/ghost_postgres:/var/lib/postgres
    networks: 
      - esnet

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0.6-alpine
    command: redis-server --requirepass "${REDIS_PASS}"
    restart: "${DOCKER_RESTART_POLICY:-unless-stopped}"
    stop_grace_period: "${DOCKER_STOP_GRACE_PERIOD:-3s}"
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis/data
    networks: 
      - esnet


  prosebit:
    build: 
      context: "."
      args:
        - "FLASK_ENV=${FLASK_ENV:-production}"
        - "NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production}"
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
      - "redis"
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_WEB_PORT:-127.0.0.1:8000}:8000"
    restart: "${DOCKER_RESTART_POLICY:-unless-stopped}"
    stop_grace_period: "${DOCKER_STOP_GRACE_PERIOD:-3s}"
    volumes:
      - "${DOCKER_WEB_VOLUME:-./public:/app/public}"
    networks:
      - esnet
      
  web: 
    depends_on:
      - prosebit
    restart: always
    build:
      context: ../nginx #added /deploy for development, remove for production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      ...
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      - "esnet"


  celery:
    build: 
      context: "."
      args: 
        - "FLASK_ENV=${FLASK_ENV:-production}"
        - "NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV:-production}"
    command: celery worker -B -l info -A 
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    depends_on:
      - "postgres"
      - "redis"
    env_file:
      - ".env"
    restart: "${DOCKER_RESTART_POLICY:-unless-stopped}"
    stop_grace_period: "${DOCKER_STOP_GRACE_PERIOD:-3s}"
    volumes:
      - "${DOCKER_WEB_VOLUME:-./public:/app/public}"
    networks:
      - "esnet"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker opens the port in the firewall itself, because your docker-compose.yml explicitly requests the port 5432 to be exposed to the world.

```
    ports:
      - '5432:5432' # removed 127.0.0.1: - adding firewalls in iptables
```

It's not clear why this is here at all, in any form. Remember that services in the same `network` can always access each other and do not need `ports` specified. Only specify `ports` to allow access from outside.

PS: You've also exposed your redis container to the world, which is probably also not what you want.